# php preg_replace tables (also tables nested in tables)

Tags: php, html-table, preg-replace

How could I replace via preg_replace a all the tables on a string? That means also the tables nested on other tables. Currently I'm using this code:

```
$pattern = '/(<table[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/table>)/is';
```

but is not "cleaning" or replacing all the tables.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Suggestion: use DOM for parsing HTML. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match opening of table, and closing of nested table as far as I can see. Replacing nested tables is a little complicated - what are you going to replace it with exactly? How do you plan to handle nesting?

If you are replacing the TABLE tags - why not treat them seperately, so replace all the opening tags with whatever, then all the closing tags with closing whatever. This will maintain the nesting.